# Не перебирает адреса в базе правильно

Tags: php, mysql, email

Я составил скрипт, который перебирает адреса в моей таблице и отмечает отправленные

```
<?php
    require "dbc.php";
    $dbcnx = @mysql_connect($DB_HOST,$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD);
    mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8'", $dbcnx);
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');
    mysql_select_db($DB_NAME, $dbcnx);
    $sends_clients_test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM law_all_mt WHERE sended = 0");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sends_clients_test)) {
        mail($row['email'], 'Subj', 'text');
        mysql_query("UPDATE law_all_mt SET sended = 1 WHERE email = $mail");
    }
?>
```

Но есть некая проблема - отправляется только на первый адрес и sended НЕ отмечается ...

Comment: Опчеатка в строке mysql_query("UPDATE law_all_mt SET sended = 1 WHERE email = $mail"); стоит $row['email'] !

Comment: И нет никаких ошибок?) Не поверю, скорее всего в этой строчке ошибка: `mail($row['email'], 'Subj', 'text');`

Comment: На самом деле я пересобрал на PHPmailer уже в-вот тут уже дико непонятно - https://yadi.sk/d/Y6w9yuXe3YwU3w

Comment: Предыдущая информация отменяется - это уже реальный скрипт .. тут приходит ТОЛЬКО первое письмо и НЕ отмечается sended

Comment: Потому что `require` надо вынести за цикл, либо переименуйте `require` в `require_once`

Comment: Ого .. вот уж нежданно-негадано.. Сработало !

Comment: Адреса пошли ВСЕ но sended так и не проставляется!

Comment: Вы от меня чуда ждете?
`mysql_query("UPDATE law_all_mt SET sended='1' WHERE email='$row['email']'")`

Comment: Я уже разобрался... Спасибо огромное за Require !